# Position in string of 4 digits number begining with "20"

Tags: php

I've got a string:

```
$string = "Something here 2014 another text here";
```

I need to detect position of the first 4 digits number that begins with "20".

So the result of the example would be 15th character of the $string.

Comment: `preg_match`, `/20\d\d/` and `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` are the tools you need. Now get to it and show us some code you've tried ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :) I tried this:
preg_match('/20\d\d/', "Something here 2014 another text here", $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);

But when you try it with string like this:
"Something here 20140 another text here"
It will also return the position which is not right. How can i add a space after those 2 digits in preg_match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have commented with code you tried, I now feel comfortable answering your question properly :) Thank you for trying first!

Your attempt:

```
preg_match('/20\d\d/', "Something here 2014 another text here",
     $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

... is absolutely correct, however as you correctly pointed out, it would also match `20140` (and indeed `12014` would match too).

To fix this behaviour, you can add word boundaries - because numbers count as word characters. Your regex becomes:

```
'/\b20\d\d\b/'
```

This will ensure that there are no numbers (or letters, for that matter) immediately before or after your target four-digit number :)

Comment: That's it! Thank you again for you effort i appreciate it. I am absolutely unexperienced with regular expressions so this really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
$needle = "20";
$pos = strpos($string , $needle);
```

EDIT:
as requested, a way to get the string from this

```
$date = substr ($string , $pos , 4 ]);
```

Comment: It's not right because you don't check 4 digits integer in the string. You're only looking for "20" string.

Comment: @Duenna Erm, nope. You would find `"20 questions for 2015"` in the wrong place, for example.